# Problems with the bibliography style with sn-chicago.bst in the new Springer Nature template

Tags: bibliographystyle, chicago-style, springernature

I have a problem with the bibliography style provided by the Springer Nature Class. According to the submission guidelines of the journal the reference section should look like that:
[image: reference style]

However none of the styles they provide in the template in latex yields this result. The closest is the sn-chicago.bst file, but it gives me some problems:

1. First names appear abbreviated, not in full: I have already changed it that modifying the format.name function and it works fine.
2. In some types (inproceedings and phdthesis) there is not a dot between the authors and the years. I managed to change that as well, modifying the functions for those types.
3. Now, see the image, in the journal type there is a space between the pages and the final dot. I don't know how to fix that.

[image: journal entry]

I was wondering if anyone knows an easy fix for my problem or if there is anyone who knows if I am missing something here.

I don't understand why they provide files that don't follow their own guidelines, and I am losing a lot of time with that. It's frustrating. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't bother with it. Submit by using their template and if they see the differences and complain, ask them to correct their files.